# Regular grammar - a*b*c*

Tags: formal-languages

I heard that a*b*c* is not regular. At the same time, i got the following regular grammar to generate it as well.

```
S → A
A → aA
A → B
B → bB
B → C
C → cC
C-> empty
```

Can anyone clarify is this grammar correct to generate a*b*c*

Thanks

Comment: Since nobody answer your literal question "Can anyone clarify [whether] this grammar [is] correct to generate a*b*c*", I would answer here with the answer: **Yes**, and so the language is regular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a*b*c*` is a perfectly regular language. In fact, the presentation is itself a proof that the language is regular; it's a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in the classical sense.

The language you're probably thinking of is `(a^n)(b^n)(c^n)`, or, since code formatting is a horrible substitute for TeX typesetting, the language of strings consisting of n a's, n b's, and n c's for all n. The important difference is that there must be the same number of a's, b's, and c's.

Comment: Hello,Thanks a lot. then if that's the case, is the language a^nb*c^n is context free?

Comment: @VinodChelladurai: If you really do mean b* in there, rather than b^n, then yes, that's context free.

Answer (score 2):

a*b*c* is indeed regular. L={a^nb^nc^n | n>=0}  is not regular.